# Laravel & vue axios get method returns Getters & Setters?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am new in Vue.js and trying to use axios to fetch data from Laravel API.
The function in backend returns an array of arrays as:

```
public function getPersonTypes()
{
    $data = [];
    $personTypes = config('codeechoo.documentation.config.personTypes');
    foreach ($personTypes as $id => $type) {
        $data[] = [
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => trans($type)
        ];
    }

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

And the Vue function in methods is:

```
fetchPersonTypes() {
           axios.get(route('api.documentation.person.types'))
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    this.personTypes = response.data;
                });
        }
```

But the console show the result as an array of objects like:

```
id: Getter & Setter
name: Getter & Setter
```

So how can I get the real values of id, name props ?

Comment: In your HTML, you can use `{{ personTypes.id  }}` && `{{ personTypes.name  }}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the data by stringifying and then parsing it back:

```
let personTypes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));
console.log(personTypes);
```

What you will see in the console now is the whole data without the getters and setters.

Comment: Thank you. Do u know why it behaves like that?

Comment: Seems to be explained here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked
````
When you pass a plain JavaScript object to a Vue instance as its data option, Vue will walk through all of its properties and convert them to getter/setters using Object.defineProperty. 
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you should call the route url directly.
NOTE: because in axios the default baseURL is already set, you don't need to type base url, only the path.
Example: instead of `axios.get(http://yoursite.com/you/path)`, just type `axios.get('your/path')`.

```
fetchPersonTypes() {
    axios.get('your/path').then(({data}) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.personTypes = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: He is specifically asking how to get the `raw` data, instead of the data with getters and setters that was set by Vue.